# Javascript todo list app. I can't delete the last remaining li and clear all button is not working, only local storage gets deleted

Tags: javascript

I encountered 2 problems regarding my todo app. I am just coding along from one of the Youtube tutorials to improve my Javascript knowledge. I cannot delete the last remaining li in my todo list but the local storage shows it is already deleted. Same as my clear all button, the local storage is already been deleted but my li's are still showing. Aside from that, after I click clear all button, I cannot delete the li's one by one even if it's still showing(my guess is the local storage is already empty and there is no more data to be deleted). Thank you for the future responses!

```js
const inputBox = document.querySelector('.input-container input')
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.input-container button')
const todo = document.querySelector('.todo-list')
const deleteAllBtn = document.querySelector('.footer button')
// input button
inputBox.onkeyup = () => {
    let userData= inputBox.value;
    if (userData.trim() != 0 ) {
        addBtn.classList.add('active')
    } else {
        addBtn.classList.remove('active');
    }
}
showTask();

//adding it to local storage
addBtn.onclick = () => {
    let userData = inputBox.value;
    let getLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("New Todo")
    if (getLocalStorage == null) {
        listArr = [];
    } else {
        listArr = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage);
    }
    listArr.push(userData);
    localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArr));
    showTask();
    addBtn.classList.remove('active');
}

//add task
function showTask() {
    let getLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("New Todo")
    if (getLocalStorage == null) {
        listArr = [];
    } else {
        listArr = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage);
    }
    const pendingNumb = document.querySelector('.pending');
    pendingNumb.textContent= listArr.length;
    let newLiTag = '';
    listArr.forEach((element, index) => {
        newLiTag += `<li> ${element} <span onclick="deleteTask(${index})";><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></li>
        `;
        todo.innerHTML = newLiTag;
        inputBox.value = '';
    });
}

//delete task
function deleteTask(index) {
    let getLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
    listArr = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage);
    listArr.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArr));
    showTask();
}

//delete all task
deleteAllBtn.onclick = () => {
    listArr = [];
    localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArr));
    showTask();
}
```

```css
.todo-list {
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 360px;
    height: 260px;
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;  
}

.todo-list li {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    margin: 5px 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.todo-list li span {
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    top: 0;
    background: #d00000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.todo-list li:hover span {
    right: 0;
}

.footer {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.footer span {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.footer button {
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    background: #d00000;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <h1>TODO list</h1>
        <div class="input-container">
            <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Input Text Here">
            <button><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
        <ul class="todo-list">
        
        </ul>

        <div class="footer">
            <span>You have<span class="pending">0</span>pending task left</span>
            <button>Clear All</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update `todo` element outside of forEach

```
function showTask() {
    let getLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("New Todo")
    if (getLocalStorage == null) {
        listArr = [];
    } else {
        listArr = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage);
    }
    const pendingNumb = document.querySelector('.pending');
    pendingNumb.textContent = listArr.length;
    let newLiTag = '';
    listArr.forEach((element, index) => {
        newLiTag += `<li> ${element} <span onclick="deleteTask(${index})";><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></li>
    `;
    });
    //move it here
    todo.innerHTML = newLiTag;
    inputBox.value = '';
}
```